# Performing brace expansion from string value into array in ZSH

Tags: zsh

Given the situation outlined in the following snippet:

```bash
# Input string provided as function argument:
input='base/{local,remote,other}$(echo hi)'
# Desired result from performing just brace expansion of the above:
expected=('base/local$(echo hi)' 'base/remote$(echo hi)' 'base/other$(echo hi)')
```

What would be the correct way in ZSH to perform *only* brace expansion on an arbitrary user-defined input string and storing the resulting array of arguments into another variable? The only way I found to force brace expansion on a value at all is using `eval`, so I’m wondering if what I’m asking is possible at all?

Some research revealed that the following might work, but this does not appear to be the case:

```bash
expanded=(${^input})
# Results in: expanded=('base/{local,remote,other}$(echo hi)')
```

Comment: `$^var` is used for things like `array=(foo bar); echo $^array-some-more` for instance.

Comment: And what shoud happen for `input='foo/"{a,b}"'` or `input='foo/\{a,b}'`?

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas: It should probably substitute on the former, but not on the latter I think? However for this question I’ll leave that undefined – anything not allowing for shell injections (executing arbitrary commands or substituting arbitrary variable values, perhaps also filename expansion and globbing) is a valid answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to do that expansion as if it was found in shell code and not the other forms of expansion, there's no operator for that, so you'll need to go with approaches that use things like `eval` after having quoted everything except the `{`, `}`, and `,`.

Maybe something like:

```
set -o extendedglob
eval "expanded=( ${input//(#m)[^{\},]##/${(qq)MATCH}} )"
```

(note that it looks like the `{1..5}` are still expanded even with the `..` quoted, same for the `-` in `{a-f}` with `braceccl` enabled).

No escaping handled above, `a\{x,y}` expands to `a\x` `a\y` and `a"{x,y}"` to `a"x"` `a"y"`.

For reference, note that ksh performs brace expansion upon unquoted parameter expansion or command substitution if the `bracexpand` option is enable and the `noglob` option is not enabled (as is the default in mksh and recent versions of ksh93).

With ksh93, an alternative way to disable globbing is to set `FIGNORE` to `*`, so in ksh93, you could do:

```
IFS= FIGNORE=*
expanded=( $input )
```

Comment: I’ve checked this with all forms of expansion and substitution documented in `zshexpn(1)` and it appears to indeed successfully suppress everything except brace expansion. (Lack of escaping is a little sad, but completely acceptable IMHO.) Thank you!

Comment: Just thinking about it, would `eval "expanded=( ${${input//(#m)[^\{\},]##/${(qq)MATCH}}//\\\'{\'/{} )"` be a decent implementation of brace-expansion with escaping, or am I missing something important there?

Comment: @ntninja, you'd also want to handle `\,` `\}` and `\\ ` and that would also not work for things like `\{{a,b}`.

Answer (score 0):

```
% x='{huh,what}'
% foo=( .(e:"reply=($x)":) )
% print -Rl $foo
huh
what
```

Which is, uh, probably too clever for its own good, as it abuses the `e` glob evaluator to replace the (ignored) glob results with the interpolated brace expansion.

Comment: It's not better (and rather worse as it also fails if `$x` contains `:`) than `eval "foo=( $x )"`

Comment: This still processes `$x` as if run through `eval` (or causes it to be “executed as shell code“ as the docs like to say), so it’s worse not just because of what @StéphaneChazelas pointed out, but since it actually obfuscates the usage of an `eval`-like capability. I’ve extended the question to highlight that anything allowing command substitution in particular is not an acceptable solution. – It’s a shame really, though… :-/

Comment: See `print -rC1 -- "$array[@]"` to print the elements of an arbitrary array one per line (on `1` `C`olumn), `print -Rl $foo` would still handle `-e` and `-n` arguments (and combinations thereof like `-ene`) as options, print an empty line for an empty array and skip empty elements.